# How to pass sysroot from Yocto to cmake

Tags: cmake, yocto

I am using a Yocto recipe to build a cmake project. In the Yocto enviroment, I confirmed that `--sysroot=my-app/recipe-sysroot` and all dependent libraries have been installed into that location. In my `CMakeList.txt`, I set `link_directories(/usr/lib)`, but error messages occur while building to indicate the dependent libraries cannot be found.
Does anyone know how to pass the Yocto sysroot environment to cmake?

My recipe,
    inherit cmake

```
DEPENDS = "\
        azure-iot-sdk-c \
        openssl \
        zlib \
        curl \
        boost \
        parson \
        gtest \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build"

EXTRA_OECMAKE = "\
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -DBUILD_SAMPLES=ON \
        -DBUILD_TESTS=ON \
        -DBUILD_TOOLS=ON \
"

FILES_${PN}-staticdev = "${libdir}/*.a"
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*.so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so rpaths"
```

And if I set the real path in my CMakeList, it works,

```
set(LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../recipe-sysroot/usr/lib")
set(STATIC_LIBRARY ${LIBRARY_DIR}/libiothub_client.a)
```

But if I set the related path according to sysroot, it does not work,

```
set(LIBRARY_DIR "/usr/lib")
```

Comment: Please post your error messages. Was this an error during the CMake 'Configure' process or compiler/linker errors?

Comment: /usr/lib/libmy.a cannot be found. Seems that the sysroot defination from Yocto does not work for cmake

Comment: What release of Yocto?

Comment: And is your recipe inheriting the cmake class?

Comment: it is the version of sumo

Comment: Can you post the recipe?

Comment: The recipe sounds broken.  I recall that Yocto uses a toolchain file when building recipes that use cmake.  The toolchain file should handle these kinds of details.

Comment: @Fred Correct. If the recipe inherits from cmake, and the cmake project is well written, all of this is magically handled (including packaging and deployment into the toolchain). We need to see the recipe to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, and I added my recipe and CMakeList

Comment: Can you also add a line of the compiler output. So we can see what's being passed to the compiler at the point of failure?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the host system `link_directories(/usr/lib)`.  You should be using `find_library()` or some other mechanism that honors the Yocto sysroot.  Your CMakeList snippet suggets that you are hardcoding an absolute path of the library to be used.  You could use `-llibiothub_client` link option and have the linker search for the library.

Comment: Yes, Fred, you are right, and after using find_library(), it works. A further question, how can I know which mechanism in cmake honors Yocto sysroot?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do:

```
set(LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../recipe-sysroot/usr/lib")
```

It is usually not necessary to have any yocto specific information in your cmake. Instead add

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
```

In your recipe add:

```
inherit cmake
```

If your cmake installs the static library and headers correctly e.g.:

```
install (TARGETS <yourtarget> DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
file(GLOB HEADERS include/*.h)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

My above advice should work, if you not install the static library using cmake you have to define an do_install task in your package recipe. For example

```
do_install() {
   install -m 0755 -d ${D}${libdir} 
   install -m 0755 ${B}/test-staticlibrary.a  ${D}/${libdir}
}
```

If you post your cmake files I can assist you further